# How to Update the Value of an ASP.NET Textbox Control on a Click Event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox, event-handling, asp.net-webcontrol

I have three asp.net textbox and button on my asp.net webform

namely textbox1, textbox2, textbox3, button1

i want if integer value of textbox2 will be substracted from textbox1 then result will be displayed in textbox3 and textbox1 and textbox2 value will remain the same ....on buttonclick event ...

**MY PROBLEM :**

*ya i know ... how to do that .... my actually problem was that ... when i click button the text in textbox1 and textbox2 and textbox3 will be disappear ... but it want it remains the same*

Comment: You should pick a title that outlines your problem.

Comment: You can use basic mathematics.

Comment: ya i know ... how to do that .... my actually problem was that ... when i click button the text in textbox1 and textbox2 and textbox3 will be disappear ... but it want it remains the same

Comment: Do you have some kind of initialization code for your textboxes in the the code-behind? If so, you need to wrap that inside of a conditional `If Not Postback`, so that the initialization only happens once.

Comment: Post some code (and a better title).

Comment: My doubt is you are using html text input and not the asp.net TextBox. The former will loose value on postback while the latter will retain.

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe the `Button.OnClientClick` to an event handler that does something like `textbox3.Text = (int.Parse(textbox1.Text)-int.Parse(textbox2.Text)).ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have enabled the "ViewState" for the controls or page. And confirm that you have no initialization for the text box value.

Answer (score -1):

Are they dynamic controls? If yes, try to recreate them in `page_load`.